# PHP Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

Tags: php, prepared-statement

So I'm having the same problem for 3 hours straight and I've been searching Stack Overflow, Google and even Bing (yes even Bing..) for the right answer but I can't seem to find a solution...

**The problem:**

I try to insert data into my database using a prepared statement, but I keep getting the same error over and over again. I'm using everything in the right order and stuff so that's not the mistake...

**My code:**

```
//INCLUDES FILES THAT HOLD ALL DATA (servername, username, ...)

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

 // prepare and bind
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (user_ref, email_user, date_created, title, tweet, description, category, filename, invoice) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
 $stmt->bind_param("sssssssss", $gebruikerID, $email, $date_created, $title, $tweet, $description, $category, $nameImage, $customUniqueId);

// set parameters and execute
$gebruikerID = $gebruikerID;
$email = $email;
$date_created = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
$title = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
$tweet = $_POST["tweet"];
$description = $_POST["project_description"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$nameImage = $nameImage;
$customUniqueId = $_GET["redirect"];

$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
```

**The error I'm getting for 3 hours straight:**

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object on line 148

Comment: `var_dump($stmt)` i bet it's false

Comment: `mysqli_prepare() returns a statement object or FALSE if an error occurred. ` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: @bassxzero Okay, You're gonna guide me trough this, you seem like you know what you're talking about... Where do I place the dump?

Comment: put it right after your prepare statement

Comment: @bassxzero You were right, it says:   bool(false)

Comment: that means that your query is invalid. Do you have phpmyadmin?

Comment: @bassxzero I have it, yes.. :)

Comment: Click the registry table, click sql, click insert. It should create a insert statement for you. Replace the query in your code with that query. Then change all of the `[value-X]` placeholders with `?`

Comment: Let me know if it's working i'll be back in 15

Comment: Try `if (!($conn->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (user_ref, email_user, date_created, title, tweet, description, category, filename, invoice) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))) { echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error; }`.

Comment: @bassxzero You are my hero now! I understand how it works now :) I should have met you 3 hours earlier... :)

Comment: You should use error reporting functions in the future, it will give you more detailed errors. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @chris85 Thank you for the tip! I will keep it in mind. Thanks to bassxzero I knew what to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For those of you that have the same problem like me, here's what was wrong:**

I had forgotten to put every row of my database in the code... So what I ended up was go to phpmyadmin and go to the table i wanted to insert some data in. Then I clicked SQL and I chose insert.

After that, I got a code and I replaced all [val-x] with ? And ended up with this code:

```
// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `projecten`(`user_ref`, `email_user`, `date_created`, `title`, `tweet`, `description`, `category`, `filename`, `invoice`, `admin_checkup`, `visible`, `project_finished`, `deleted`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt->bind_param("sssssssssssss", $gebruikerID, $email, $date_created, $title, $tweet, $description, $category, $nameImage, $customUniqueId, $adminCheck, $visible, $project_finished, $deleted);

// set parameters and execute
$gebruikerID = $gebruikerID;
$email = $email;
$date_created = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
$title = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
$tweet = $_POST["tweet"];
$description = $_POST["project_description"];
$category = $_POST["category"];
$nameImage = $nameImage;
$customUniqueId = $_GET["redirect"];
$adminCheck = "0";
$visible = "0";
$project_finished = "0";
$deleted = "0";

$stmt->execute();
```

I hope this helps you guys out!